# I am unable to consume foreign key data in mvc client from web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, foreign-keys

I am new to programming web api and consuming in mvc http client. I have multiple tables in my database with relationship. I have created web api and entity frame work in a separate project. Mvc client in separate project.

I am able to consume data if i dont have any relationship in database table. so here I am struggling to find the solution.  Here is my code

## Product controller (Web api)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(MVCProduct products)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2244/api/Products");
     var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MVCProduct>("Products", products);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Saved Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }
```

## MVC Category Model class

```
public class MVCcategory
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string CId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<MVCProduct> Products { get; set; }

}
```

## MVC Product Model class

```
public class MVCProduct
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? BatchNo { get; set; }
    public decimal? BuyPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal? SellPrice { get; set; }
    public int? CId { get; set; }

    public MVCcategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

## Product controller(MVC)

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(MVCProduct products)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:2244/api/Products");

        //HTTP POST
        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MVCProduct>("Products", products);
        postTask.Wait();

        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Saved Successfully";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server Error. Please contact administrator.");

    return View(products);
}
```

## Add View

```
@model MyProductMVC.Models.MVCProduct

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutCustom.cshtml";
}

<h2>Add</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>MVCProduct</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BatchNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BatchNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BatchNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BuyPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BuyPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BuyPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SellPrice, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SellPrice, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SellPrice, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.DropDownList("CId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })


                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Your question would receive better answers if you clarified the problem more explicitly. You've given us some code, what parts of it are you having trouble stitching together? What is your intended outcome?

Comment: Why does the MVC endpoint POSTs to the WebAPI endpoint that POSTs to itself?

Comment: Could you also give us the class definitions and inheritances for your MVC and web api product controller?

Comment: @harshitha  thank you for your kind reply to my question. Actually I'm trying to add products based on category with the help of drop down in add product view.